# Change position of other photos by SlideDown & SlideUp in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I use JQuery `slideDown` & `slideUp` to make a slide show:

```
$(".arrow-right").click(function(){
  $("img.book1").slideUp(500);
  $("img.book2").slideDown(800);
});

$(".arrow-left").click(function(){
  $("img.book2").slideUp(500);
  $("img.book1").slideDown(800);
});
```

And in this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eylay/L1op33oh/2/) you can see that it effects on the other photos. (In the fiddle you see that the issue is the wooden shelf moving up & down)
I have tried so many things but I couldn't solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of fixing the `height`. Or may be in best, using `min-height`:

```
ul li:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 145px;
}
```

Comment: Tnx, I added that, but still the issue isn't solved: https://jsfiddle.net/eylay/L1op33oh/3/